# Signal-Desktop: how to export messages?

Tags: backup, signal-messenger

How can `signal-desktop` messages be exported?

I want to backup my correspondence.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just save this in a file `<yourFilename>`:

```
sigBase="${HOME}/.config/Signal/";
key=$( /usr/bin/jq -r '."key"' ${sigBase}config.json );
db="${HOME}/.config/Signal/sql/db.sqlite";
clearTextMsgs="${sigBase}clearTextMsgs.csv";

/usr/bin/sqlcipher -list -noheader "$db" "PRAGMA key = \"x'"$key"'\";select json from messages;" > "$clearTextMsgs";
```

and call it via `bash <yourFilename>`. Or render it executable with `chmod 700 <yourFilename>` and call it directly: `./<yourFilename>`

This script uses `sqlcipher` and `jq` with signal-desktop's database key to open, decrypt and extract all messages in `JSON` format into `clearTextMsgs.csv` inside your signal-desktop folder `~/.config/Signal`.

Besides the key extraction by filtering JSON with `jq` (from `~/.config/Signal/config.json`), the crucial bit happens here:

```
sqlcipher -list -noheader <DB> <SQL>
```

where `<SQL>` contains the `PRAGMA key` definition and the actual SQL statement (`SELECT json FROM messages;`).

One can then use `jq` to access any key/value from the messages backup.

You have to install `sqlcipher` and `jq` for that:

```
sudo apt install sqlcipher jq
```

**Note:**

While this does extract all messages, we need to specify that "`all`" in signal-desktop has the meaning of "`all messages actually loaded`". So, in order to extract every single message, the slider of the active contact has to be slid way up, then signal-desktop will load previously not availalble messages (lather rinse repeat until satisfied). Do so as far in the past you would want your messages loaded. This gets tedious quite quickly. Remember to do so for all of your contacts' histories.

Having that said, it is technically feasable to backup your message history, in practice it is a manual job. A way around this might be a cron job backing up all recent messages, maybe once a day. Then this is likely to contain duplicates and might miss messages in case signal-desktop has been restarted.

In any case, this method is working fine if the (not too far -- read: a couple of months maybe) history is to be searched programmatically once in a while.

Comment: Does this method export only the message, or also the media? Is a tool like https://github.com/IdealChain/signal-media-exporter additionaly needed? Also, related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/25132477/2657549 https://stackoverflow.com/q/25132477/2657549 There is also a workaround detailed at https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/2516#issuecomment-442797638

Comment: Plain ol' ASCII, only.

Comment: tried this on Ubuntu 19.10, but I just get the error `Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
`

Comment: You need minimum sqlcipher version 3.30 for this to work, compile manually like: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/ and then change the last line to `/usr/local/bin/sqlcipher`

Comment: Unfortunately my version doesn't create csv output but json, it could be read if you dump the output file to `|tail -n +2 |jq . ` but that is quite unhandy. Here is a solution how you export it by hand: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/2516#issuecomment-442797638

Comment: @rubo77 I just tried this (Debian testing) and I also get the error, with sqlcipher 3.4.1. You mentioned version 3.30 but no such version exists, did you mean 3.3.0? It seems to not be enough any more unfortunately. EDIT: After locally building sqlcipher 4.4.0, it works. :)

Comment: I can confirm, I compiled version 4.4.3 of sqlcipher, it works

Comment: @Gen.Stack I am getting stuck with this script. I get the errors: `bash sqlite-to-csv.sh
jq: error: Could not open file /Users/roiholtzman/Library/Application\: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file Support/Signal/config.json: No such file or directory
sqlite-to-csv.sh: line 15: /Users/roiholtzman/Library/Application\ Support/Signal/backup-desktop.csv: No such file or directory`. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

[sigtop](https://github.com/tbvdm/sigtop) worked for me, and has options for export formats.

Answer (score 1):

Basically as [Gen.Stack answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/505009/revisions), but **more worked-out instructions for Debian**.

I also removed some unnecessary complexity. E.g.: `jq '."key"'` can also just be written as `jq .key` since none of these characters are dynamic and so will never need escaping with two layers of quotes. Variables like `"$HOME"` are still quoted, since those could contain characters that need quoting.

1. You need to compile sqlcipher from source, at least as of 2022 even the version in sid is not new enough as per [rubo77's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505008/signal-desktop-how-to-export-messages#comment1062262_505009)

   1. Install dependencies:
      `apt install build-essential libssl-dev tcl libsqlite3-dev`
      Not sure if libsqlite3-dev is required, but I installed it as part of debugging stuff.
      If you are missing a dependency but `./configure` ran correctly and you tried to `make`, then subsequent builds will fail until you manually remove `sqlite3.h`, see https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/157
   2. Download the code:
      `git clone https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.git`
      `cd sqlcipher`
   3. Configure with dynamic linking, then compile:
      `./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"`
      `make`
2. Install `jq` to extract your database encryption key:
   `apt install jq`
3. Set the environment variables for convenience:
   `db="$HOME/.config/Signal/sql/db.sqlite"`
   `key="$(jq -r .key "$HOME/.config/Signal/config.json")`"
4. Export the messages. Note that I use `./sqlcipher` below. If you are not in the compilation directory anymore, you should specify the path, for example: `~/Downloads/sqlcipher/sqlcipher -list ...`.

   - Export **just your `messages` table**:
     `./sqlcipher -list -noheader "$db" "PRAGMA key = \"x'"$key"'\";select json from messages;" > Signal_messages.jsonl`
   - Export **the whole database** with the `.dump` command:
     `echo -e 'PRAGMA key = "x'\'"$key"\''";\n.dump\n' | ./sqlcipher -list -noheader "$db" > Signal_database.sql`
   - Just **browse the database**:

     ```
     $ echo "$key"
     SECRETSECRET
     $ ./sqlcipher -list -noheader "$db"
     sqlite> PRAGMA key = "x'SECRETSECRET'";
     ok
     sqlite> .tables
     attachment_downloads   messages_fts_config    sessions
     badgeImageFiles        messages_fts_content   signedPreKeys
     ...
     ```

   Note that the quotes around the key are all necessary and that the "ok" does not mean that it has checked your key. If you get a "file is not a database" when running something like `.tables` then, most likely, you got the wrong key or typo'd something or selected the wrong file (or, in a rare case perhaps, the file could be damaged damaged).

Et voilá, wasn't that easy? Why would Signal add a backup feature when you can just do the above!

Answer (score 0):

Find your encrypted db.sqlite database (the decryption key is in the config.json file).
Depending on your OS and how you install Signal you may find these files in one of these locations:

Linux:

- `~/.config/Signal/`
- `~/.var/app/org.signal.Signal/config/Signal`

Windows:

- `%AppData%\Signal\config.json`

Mac OS:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Signal`

What you want to do is execute this SQL query:

```
SELECT M.sent_at, M.source, C.name, M.type, M.body
  FROM messages AS M
      JOIN conversations AS C
          ON M.conversationId = C.id
ORDER BY M.sent_at;
```

It returns all messages in a reasonable format:
timestamp; phone number; conversation name; incoming/outgoing; message content

---

If you want a GUI, you can use [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/).
Open sqlitebrowser, click Open, select Raw Key, enter your key with a leading `0x` as shown in the screenshot, select `SQLCipher 4 defaults`, click okay:
[image]
Go to the `Execute SQL` tab and paste the aforementioned query, then click the blue triangular play button to execute the query:
[image]